# Windows pdf-tools-install no such program: autoreconf

Tags: init-file, package, package-repositories, pdf-tools

I'm trying to install pdf-tools on my Windows System, I'm using the same config as for Arch Linux where this error is fixed by installing the arch linux pdf-tools package via pacman.

Obviously this is not possible with Windows.

The error is that pdf-tools-install tries to build the epdfinfo program.

To fix another error during this building process I had to install mysys64 and now there is the new error log

```
    c\:/Users/stackoverflow/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/pdf-tools-1.0/server/autobuild -i 
    
    c\:/Users/stackoverflow/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/pdf-tools-1.0/
        ---------------------------
            Installing packages    
        ---------------------------
        pacman -S --needed base-devel
                              mingw-w64-x86_64-libpng
                              mingw-w64-x86_64-poppler
                              mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
                              mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib
        error: failed to init transaction (unable to lock database)
        error: could not lock database: File exists
          if you're sure a package manager is not already
          running, you can remove /var/lib/pacman/db.lck
---------------------------
 Configuring and compiling 
---------------------------
No such program: autoreconf
```

Do you know how to fix this? I thought that it would be less pain to make pdf-tools work on every machine.

Maybe something is wrong with my init.el

```
    (require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
;(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
;  (package-refresh-contents)
;  (package-install 'use-package))
;'(eval-when-compile
;  (require 'use-package))



(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
(load-theme 'zenburn t)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-safe-themes
   '("1410978f21ad4be59873f27d5020500803a747d2f6ef617608d53c3cf63cc75b" default))
 '(package-selected-packages '(org-roam pdf-tools ## auctex)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )





(require 'pdf-tools)
(pdf-tools-build-server (expand-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory "elpa/pdf-tools-1.0")) nil nil nil (expand-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory "elpa/pdf-tools-1.0/server")))

(pdf-tools-install)



  (use-package pdf-tools
:init
(pdf-tools-install)
:config
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Tools"))
      TeX-view-program-list '(("PDF Tools" TeX-pdf-tools-sync-view))
      TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
(add-hook 'TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions #'TeX-revert-document-buffer)
(setq pdf-view-use-scaling t)
(setq pdf-view-resize-factor 1.05)
:bind (:map pdf-view-mode-map
            ("<left>" . pdf-view-previous-page-command)
            ("<right>" . pdf-view-next-page-command)))

      (setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
(setq font-latex-fontify-script nil)
(setq reftex-extra-bindings t)  ;; Must be befor require reftex! (require 'reftex) (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex) (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda() (display-line-numbers-mode 1))) (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda() (visual-line-mode 1))) (setq reftex-plug-into-auctex t)
;; magic words: (setq reftex-label-alist '((nil ?e nil nil nil ("system" "systems" "estimate" "estimates")))) (setq TeX-save-query nil)



;; turn off welcome window, inhibit startup message
;; setq to indicate function
;; inhibit-startup-message to true
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
```

Also tested this config on macOS now and it also tries to build epdfinfo

Edit:

To fix the error with the locked database I had to remove msys64/var/lib/pacman/db.lck but I still get the error that autoreconf is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the following config for every machine I have, i.e. Windows 11, Arch Linux & macOS:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
;; Comment/uncomment this line to enable MELPA Stable if desired.  See `package-archive-priorities`
;; and `package-pinned-packages`. Most users will not need or want to do this.
;;(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)


(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
(load-theme 'zenburn t)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-safe-themes
   '("1410978f21ad4be59873f27d5020500803a747d2f6ef617608d53c3cf63cc75b" default))
 '(package-selected-packages '(org-roam pdf-tools ## auctex)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )








  (use-package pdf-tools
:init
(pdf-tools-install)
:config
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Tools"))
      TeX-view-program-list '(("PDF Tools" TeX-pdf-tools-sync-view))
      TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
(add-hook 'TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions #'TeX-revert-document-buffer)
(setq pdf-view-use-scaling t)
(setq pdf-view-resize-factor 1.05)
:bind (:map pdf-view-mode-map
            ("<left>" . pdf-view-previous-page-command)
            ("<right>" . pdf-view-next-page-command)))

      (setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
(setq font-latex-fontify-script nil)
(setq reftex-extra-bindings t)  ;; Must be befor require reftex! (require 'reftex) (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex) (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda() (display-line-numbers-mode 1))) (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda() (visual-line-mode 1))) (setq reftex-plug-into-auctex t)
;; magic words: (setq reftex-label-alist '((nil ?e nil nil nil ("system" "systems" "estimate" "estimates")))) (setq TeX-save-query nil)



;; turn off welcome window, inhibit startup message
;; setq to indicate function
;; inhibit-startup-message to true
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
```

Basically I had to reinstall pdf-tools from MEPA.

And in MSYS64 I did

```
$ pacman -Syu
$ pacman -S base-devel
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libpng
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-poppler
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-imagemagick
```

I hope this helps someone from the future.